# The -bind-to command in Microsoft MPI

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi, ms-mpi

On Ubuntu with Open MPI installed, I can use -bind-to command to bind each of the processes to a physical core like `mpiexec -np 4 -bind-to core python mycode.py`. Now I have to work on Windows with MS-MPI installed, I don't know if there is a similar function.

I have tried to use -affinity and -affinity_layout according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/mpiexec?view=hpc16-ps) like

`mpiexec -np 4 -affinity -affinity_layout spread:P python mycode.py`

which is supposed to raising error on my 2 physical cores laptop. But it works fine. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Affinity with Microsoft MPI *does* work; Microsoft MPI just does not complain when multiple ranks land at a single core (i.e. when you oversubscribe).

One can find the affinities of running processes in "Task Manager > Details > (right click on process) > Set affinity".

So, on my 10-core machine, running

```
mpiexec -n 2 -affinity -affinity_layout spread:P notepad.exe
```

produces affinities

```
rank | 0 | 1 |
CPU  | 0 | 5 |
```

while running

```
mpiexec -n 11 -affinity -affinity_layout spread:P notepad.exe
```

results in

```
rank | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
CPU  | 0 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 8 | 4 | 9 | 0  |
```

i.e., the mapping silently wraps around when all cores are exhausted.